# Method of finding "closest" common multiple?

Tags: statistics, gcd-and-lcm

I am trying to program a script to do this, but I can't find any existing methods, so I hope you have any ideas.
The problem is similar to LCM, but the numbers are inaccurate, so I have to find the closest solution.

Example: I have the numbers 1296, 306, 8928, 2466, 1881.
They should be multiples of the number 180, but since the numbers are inaccurate,
I need to find a number that is close to 180, that gives the least amount of error as multiple for the set of numbers.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: So you want to find $\frac {1296}{180}=7.2\approx 7$ so $7*180 =1260$ and $\frac {306}{180}=1.7\approx 2$ so $2*180 = 360$ and $8928\approx 50*180=9000$ etc???  It's not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: $1296=7.2\times 180\approx 7*180=1260; 306=1.7*180\approx 2*180=360; 8928=49.6*180\approx 50*180=9000; 2466=13.7*180\equiv 14*180=2520; 1881= 10.45*180\approx 10*180 = 1800$.  Is that what you are trying to do?  If so just divide each number by $180$ and round and then muliply by $180$.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by what you intend by "I need to find a number that is close to 180, that gives the least amount of error as multiple for the set of numbers."

I am guessing that you want each number $n$ *converted* to $m$, where $m$ is the closest multiple of $180$ to $n$.  Assuming so, after the conversion, you could then (for example) compute the lcm of $\{m_1, m_2, m_3, m_4, m_5\}$ using standard methods.

If my guess and subsequent analysis is accurate, then your query reduces to how to convert a positive integer $n$ into $m$.

Apply the Euclidean Algorithm so that 
$n = (90\times P) + r$, 
where $P \,\in \{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ and $r \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, 89\}.$

Then, if $P$ is even, then the closest multiple
$$m = 180 \times \left(\frac{P}{2}\right).$$

Alternatively, if $P$ is odd, then the closest multiple
$$m = 180 \times \left(\frac{P+1}{2}\right).$$

The only wrinkle is that if $P$ is odd and $r = 0$, then $n$ is equidistant between two multiples of 180 and my algorithm is (then) automatically "rounding up".